# Usage of "ohnehin" and "immerhin"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What's the difference between *ohnehin* and *immerhin*? Both mean "anyway" in my dictionary and I wonder if they're interchangeable.

> Ich kann ohnehin/immerhin nicht gehen, denn ich arbeite.

Comment: Which dictionary are you using? Maybe you should consider a bigger one that gives you more than one translation. Often the difference will become clear then. Also, you could use Linguee.com where you'll see words in context.

Comment: dict.cc and de.wiktionary.org as well as duden.de are valuable dictionaries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Immerhin* means “not bad, but could be better”:

> Ich bin immer noch krank, aber immerhin habe ich keinen Schnupfen mehr. – I am still ill, but at least I do not have a cold anymore.

It can be used as a single-word statement to appreciate a result that could be better.

> Arzt: »Sie sind immer noch krank, aber haben keinen Schnupfen mehr.« – Patient: »Immerhin.« — Medic: “You are still ill, but you do not have a cold anymore.” – Patient: “Better than nothing.“

*Ohnehin* means, that a problem or situation already exists, e.g.:

> Jetzt habe ich Schnupfen, aber ich war ohnehin schon krank. – Now I have a cold, but I was ill anyway.

So they are not interchangeable.

Comment: It seems to me that *immerhin* can be replaced by *trotzdem* ?